# Empty OpenMP for loop taking 5 ms

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I have the following C++ code in test.cpp:

```
int myfun(){
double time1, time2;
time1 = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int group_id = 0; group_id < 1; ++group_id){ }

time2 = omp_get_wtime();
printf("computation took %.3f ms\n", (time2-time1)*1000);
return 0;
}
```

I compile this into a shared library using

```
g++ -c -fPIC -fopenmp -std=c++11 -Wall -march=native -O3 -o test.o test.cpp
```

followed by

```
g++ -shared -fopenmp -o mylib.so test.o
```

When I run the function myfun() (I call it from a python program in case this matters), I get the following output:

```
computation took 5.992 ms
```

If I comment out the #pragma directive, I of course get

```
computation took 0.000 ms
```

Now I understand that there is some overhead to be expected when using openmp, but this seems unreasonable. What am I missing here?

Comment: Some implementations keep the OMP thread spun up for some time in case it gets more work (yours is hardly a typical task)

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419622/openmp-overhead-calculation). You can measure the openMP thread creation overhead using the [EPPC micro-benchmarks](https://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/research/computing/performance-characterisation-and-benchmarking/epcc-openmp-micro-benchmark-suite).

Comment: I'd like to add that what #pragma is commented out the for loop is simply spinning without any variables being used later in the function. Therefore it could be possible that the compiler optimized away the useless loop, thus reducing execution time

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. Multithreaded programming gives additional overhead such as creating threads, synchronizing, etc. But correctly applied multithreaded programming gives a win. Choose sequential or multithreaded implementation depending on their effectiveness.
In my example threads are created in the first call and then they are using. But it depends on the implementation:

```
int main()
{
    myfun();
    myfun();
    myfun();
    myfun();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
computation took 2.510 ms
computation took 0.082 ms
computation took 0.046 ms
computation took 0.043 ms
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Indeed thread creation overhead looks like what I'm seeing. As you show in your example, it looks like threads will be re-used in subsequent calls to the function, and this is what I would like to have happen in my use case. However, for some reason, in the context of a shared library, it looks like threads are being created / deleted with each call of my function. Is there a way to specify to openmp that the threads should be kept alive for the duration of the program's process?